# What is the correct C++ way to assign a function pointer to a function of typedef in a constexpr struct?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, constexpr

Forgive me if the question wording isn't completely accurate, but what I am tryin to do (what I have done while compiling with MSVC /std:c++latest) is create a constexpr struct of config items for a really basic shell class.  Some of those items are application/platform dependent io functions, read and write.  The following code works in my VS solution that I tinker with before adding to an existing project.

... from header only class

```
typedef size_t (*read_func_t)(void* const buf, size_t nbytes);
typedef size_t (*write_func_t)(const void* buf, size_t nbytes);

typedef struct shell_cfg_t {
  size_t buffer_size;
  read_func_t read;
  write_func_t write;
  size_t max_args;
} shell_cfg_t;

template<shell_cfg_t cfg>
class Shell
{
  public:

    Shell(const cmd_t * const cmd_table)
    : m_buf{}
    , m_args{}
    , m_read{cfg.read}
    , m_write{cfg.write}
    {
      ms_cmd_table = cmd_table;
    }
};
```

... from main.cpp

```
static size_t read_impl(void* const buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  // some code
  return bytes_read;
}

static size_t write_impl(const void* buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  // some code
  return bytes_written;
}

constexpr shell_cfg_t cfg =
{
  .buffer_size = 64,
  .read = read_impl,
  .write = write_impl,
  .max_args = 8
};

int main()
{
  Shell<cfg> sh(shell_cmd_table);

  std::string user_input_str;
  std::getline(std::cin, user_input_str);
  user_input_str += sh.kEoL;

  byte_recvd_handler((uint8_t*)(user_input_str.data()), user_input_str.length());

  sh.process();

  return 0;
}
```

The problem code here seems to be assigning read_impl and write_impl to .read and .write of the struct. The error from GNU 10.2.0 is below (full error at the bottom):

`"error: 'read_impl' is not a valid template argument of type 'size_t (*)(void*, size_t)' {aka 'long long unsigned int (*)(void*, long long unsigned int)'} because 'read_impl' is not a variable, .read = read_impl,"`

Is there a difference in the C++20 implementations between GCC and MSVC that I'm dealing with, or is this code incorrect per standard?  The constexpr struct and named initialization list is a new thing I think, but I don't think assigning a function pointer that way has anything to do with the new std standard. The alternative is a runtime check for the read/write functions not being nullptr, which was the whole point of using the config struct with a template. Is there a better way to do this that might be compatible with C++17?

Edit:
... full error related to this file. the whole project output would be 1000+ lines

```
../Examples/Example_Shell.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../Examples/Example_Shell.cpp:47:11: error: 'read_impl' is not a valid template argument of type 'size_t (*)(void*, size_t)' {aka 'long long unsigned int (*)(void*, long long unsigned int)'} because 'read_impl' is not a variable
   47 |   .read = read_impl,
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
../Examples/Example_Shell.cpp:71:28: error: invalid conversion from 'const cmd_t*' {aka 'const Kernel::Shell::cmd_t*'} to 'int' [-fpermissive]
   71 |   Kernel::Shell::Term<cfg> sh(shell_cmd_table);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            const cmd_t* {aka const Kernel::Shell::cmd_t*}
../Examples/Example_Shell.cpp:75:24: error: request for member 'kEoL' in 'sh', which is of non-class type 'int'
   75 |   user_input_str += sh.kEoL; // for example only. getline does not capture end line
      |                        ^~~~
../Examples/Example_Shell.cpp:79:6: error: request for member 'process' in 'sh', which is of non-class type 'int'
   79 |   sh.process();
      |      ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is the error you show the only output you get when you build? If not, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question. And please add a comment on the line(s) where you get the error(s).

Comment: I do not get it. Why you need template parameter if you are doing copy of values into a fields of `Shell`?

Comment: It is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83258).

Answer (score 1):

Instead defining this `constexpr` define a class which will then used by template as type parameter:

```cpp
struct shell_default_cfg_t
{
    size_t buffer_size;
    read_func_t read;
    /* static */ size_t read(void* const buf, size_t nbytes) const {
       return read_impl(buf, nbytes);
    }

    /* static */ size_t write_impl(const void* buf, size_t nbytes) {
       return write_impl(buf, nbytes);
    }
};

template<typename Cfg>
class Shell
{
  public:

    Shell(const cmd_t * const cmd_table, Cfg cfg)
    : m_buf{}
    , m_args{}
    , m_cfg{std::move(cfg)}
    {
      ms_cmd_table = cmd_table;
    }

    size_t read(void* const buf, size_t nbytes) const {
       return cfg.read(buf, nbytes);
    }

    Cfg m_cfg;
};
```